# Oracle Resource Manager is not allocating CPU to Query

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, resourcemanager

Oracle Resource Manager is not allocating CPU to Query. Our application is executing many queries in the same session but somehow it is always getting stuck at one particular query from today(Previously it was running fine from more than 3 years) and on checking with DBA it is found that it is waiting for event **resmgr:cpu quantum**

Although when I ran the same query from my SQL developer it is running without any issue. I have checked there are no locks and load on CPU is also minimal but I believe it doesn't matter as query is not even getting CPU to execute.

Below are my Oracle Version details

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production,

PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
,
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"

TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Can someone please guide what can be the cause that Resource manager is not allocating CPU for this particular query only. There are no hints mentioned in the query

Answer (score 0):

To effectively monitor and tune the Database Resource Manager, you must design
a representative environment.  The Database Resource Manager works best in
large production environments in which system utilization is high.  If a test
places insufficient load on the system, measured CPU allocations can be very
different from the allocations specified in the active resource plan.

to do this

- Create a job which will perform some statistics.
- Create a plan
- Create Consumer Groups
- Create plan directives
- Validate and submit the plan
- Group switching
- Assign the user 'CRC' of the database a default initial consumer group at connection time

Answer (score 0):

this is because DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN was active
check these links:

https://www.bestremotedba.com/2016/12/25/how-to-resmgr-cpu-quantum-wait/

https://askdba.org/weblog/2012/01/user-sessions-stuck-on-resmgrcpu-quantum-wait-event/

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tasks005.htm#ADMIN11840

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.